# search api in c# asynchronous fetching of searched tweets

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, twitter

any one know about how to do the asynchronous fetching though already searched tweets like twitter shows "x New Tweets" on twitter searched result pane.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain your case further, and tell us what you have tried already.

Comment: i did search functionality using search api with linqtotwitter wrapper but i need to show the new tweet count like twitter shows on search result pane on twitter home page like wise i need to implement that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got an answer my question my self.. the solution is followed by below url
http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/demo/Realtime-ticker/